# python3 JSON creation using the list name as JSON key

Tags: python, json

I am not familiar with JSON manipulation and I am trying to produce a JSON file: like this

```
{
"employee":"mike","brakes":"15,60","individual":"1","time":"8:00",
"employee":"dany","brakes":"15,60","individual":"1","time":"8:00"
}
```

so basically for every employee the same info.

```
import json
import io
try:
    to_unicode = unicode
except NameError:
    to_unicode = str

brakes = '15,60'
individual = '1'
time = '8:00'

list = ['mike', 'dany']
new = []
for i in list:
    new.append({i:brakes})

with io.open('file.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    for i in new:
        str_ = json.dumps(i,
                          indent=4, sort_keys=True,
                          separators=(',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
        outfile.write(to_unicode(str_))
```

that produces:

{
    "mike": "15,60"
}{
    "dany": "15,60"
}

Do you have any idea how to achieve my goal?

Comment: the desired JSON result you give at the beginning is not valid, so you cannot possibly have this result. What you seem to be looking for is a **list** of **mappings**.

Answer (score 0):

Using `json` module.

**Ex:**

```
import json

brakes = '15,60'
individual = '1'
time = '8:00'

employees = ['mike', 'dany']
result = [{"employee": employee, "brakes": brakes, "individual": individual, "time": time}
          for employee in employees]

with open('file.json', "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile,
              indent=4, sort_keys=True,
              separators=(',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, the method works but still builds a diffrent format in this case a list, I am looking for a very specific format such the presented on the question, thank for the help

Comment: you cannot have a dictionary with duplicate keys.